# Routing on areas and specific actions with Attribute decorator are not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the Product controller which has a defined area routing:

```
[Area("Product")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexJson()
    {
        return View("IndexJson");
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateProduct(int id)
    {
            //Some processing code...
            return PartialView("Update", product);
    }
}
```

In Programs.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

> https://localhost:7207/Product/Products/IndexJson -> working fine
> https://localhost:7207/Product/Products/UpdateProduct/1 -> Returns 404
> but if I remove [HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)}")] then works ok. Why is
> this happen ? I need this decorator in order to validate the params

Comment: You should not use route constraints for input validation! If you'd enter a negative id it would result in a `404` not found response, where as an invalid input _should_ return a `400` Bad request status code.
Btw: feel free to accept any answer that helped you on your previous question.

Comment: @Jackdaw is it correct to have both attributes ?

Comment: I know its working , but i am wondering if its correct pattern

Comment: @Jackdaw just because you could, doesn't mean you should. The link you've posted tells excactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the route constraints here, it will **override the default MVC route template** you defined in the `Program.cs`. So the correct url should be:`https://localhost:7207/1`.

If you want to request the url like what your MVC template configures, you need change the attribute like below:

```
[HttpGet("/[area]/[controller]/[action]/{id:int:min(1)}")]
```

Besides, don't use constraints for input validation. If constraints are used for input validation, invalid input results in a `404` Not Found response. Invalid input should produce a `400` Bad Request with an appropriate error message. Route constraints are used to disambiguate similar routes, not to validate the inputs for a particular route.